# JSON 3D model textures are not shown

Tags: json, three.js, textures, webgl, 3d-model

I have been able to load and render 3D models along corresponding textures from 3D model files with OBJ format using three.js API. I wanted to try loading models with JSON (.js) format. So I download a 3D model ([this mill](http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/medieval-mill-or-blacksmith-48408.html)) and converted it to JSON format using [mrdoob python script](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py). It outputted a .js file along with textures inside a folder. I copied everything intact to my localhost folder and inserted below code into my html page hoping to get the mill with all textures:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();  
loader.load( 'mill.js', function ( geometry ) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({overdraw: true}));
    mesh.scale.set(0.005, 0.005, 0.005);
    mesh.castShadow=true;
    scene.add( mesh );  });
```

But the result I got is this:
[image: mill without texture]

Obviously it lacks corresponding textures. i had a look inside `mill.js` file; although I didn't understand it, I could see the textures are introduced inside `materials` array. While JSON file refers to corresponding textures, what should I do in my code to bring textures to model surfaces?